# Where are npm scripts actually run from?

Tags: npm, webpack, devops

If I run

> npm run client

in my_directory, it will translate to:

> webpack -w --mode production --config ./webpack.config.js

However, if I am in my_directory and I manually type in the above command, I get:

> zsh: command not found: webpack

Also, can I change things so that I can run from my_directory.  This is a two part question if possible.

I was expecting to be able to run webpack manually without an npm script.

Answer (score 1):

`webpack` is installed in `node_modules/.bin/`, so you can do

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack -w --mode production --config ./webpack.config.js
```

Answer (score 1):

if you visit `node_modules/.bin` directory, you will see all the executables in your project are stored here. Those binaries are symlinked to the package's directory inside node_modules. When you run `npm run`, local `node_modules/.bin` directory is added to the [PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them). When you execute the script, it actually executes from local `node_modules/.bin`.

If you want to manually write `webpack` to terminal you should install `webpack` globally, its executable directory will be added to PATH so that you can run it from terminal. Since you did not install `webpack` globally, it has no executable in your machine.

```
 sudo npm i -g webpack
```

this will install `webpack` in your actual machine, not in your project.

```
npm root -g
```

this will show where your global modules installed.

But installing packages globally is not a good practice. let' 's say your app works with `webpack5` now but in the future `webpack6` is released and you upgraded `webpack` to 6 (or someone cloned your project and its system has webpack6) but your old project might break because of breaking changes in webpack6 version.